# Copy and paste a value if checkbox true

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was wondering if there is a script or formula to do the following. Basically the whole idea is to make an add to favorites checkbox and a delete from favorites checkbox, so a user will be able to add his favorite products from the product list sheet into a favorites list sheet and monitor only those.

Sample Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qNmkmNWLqhysgNBbvnSO1AEn_j01Su14doAJpRrPEjE

1. Add to favorites checkbox:

> If Items!B3=True (tick checkbox) then copy Items!E1 and paste to Favorites!A2 if it's empty, if it's not empty paste to Favorites!A2 +1 cell (eg. Favorites!A3, Favorites!A4 etc.) then make Favorites!B3=False (untick checkbox). Also check if copied value already exist then do not paste and make Favorites!B3=False (untick checkbox).

2. Remove from favorites checkbox:

> If Items!B4=True (tick checkbox) then filter Items!E1 with Favorites!A:A and delete the matched value from Favorites!A:A, then make Items!B4=False (untick checkbox).

Some further explanation:
https://puu.sh/ISxAD/6d38c87af3.png
https://puu.sh/ISxFC/14bf4a6520.png

Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `if it's not empty paste to Sheet2!A2 +1 cell`, the cell `Sheet1!B2` is the number value? If my understanding is correct, I cannot understand `Also check if copied value already exist`. And, I cannot understand `If Sheet1!A3=True (tick checkbox) then filter Sheet1!B2 with Sheet2!A:A and delete the matched value from Sheet2!A:A, then make Sheet1!A3=False (untick checkbox).`. And also, I cannot understand the relationship between `Add to favorites checkbox` and `Remove from favorites checkbox`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Hey I might have an idea but could you show a sample input and output. To make sure I match your desired output?

Comment: If possible also share a sample Spreadsheet

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I added a sample spreadsheet and two images explaining the functions to help you understand in depth.

Comment: hey @mrfrankito, can you share what you have tried so far as well? would you like a solution which uses Apps Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go (updated):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Charts') return;
  if (e.range.columnStart != 7) return;
  if (e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value == 'TRUE') add_item(e);
  if (e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value == 'TRUE') remove_item(e);
}

function add_item(e) {
  var [ss, item, favs_sheet, favs_range, favs, header] = get_variables(e);
  if (favs.includes(item)) { ss.toast(item + ' is already in favorites'); return}
  
  favs.push(item);
  favs = [header, ...favs.sort()].map(x => [x]);
  favs_sheet.getRange(1,1,favs.length,favs[0].length).setValues(favs);
  ss.toast(item + ' was added');
}

function remove_item(e) {
  var [ss, item, favs_sheet, favs_range, favs, header] = get_variables(e);
  if (!favs.includes(item)) { ss.toast(item + ' was not found among favorites'); return }
  
  favs = [header, ...favs.filter(x => x != item).sort()].map(x => [x]);
  favs_range.clear();
  favs_sheet.getRange(1,1,favs.length,favs[0].length).setValues(favs);
  ss.toast(item + ' was removed');
}

function get_variables(e) {
  e.range.uncheck();
  var ss = e.source;
  var item = e.range.getSheet().getRange('B2').getValue();
  var favs_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Favorites');
  var favs_range = favs_sheet.getRange('A:A');
  var favs = favs_range.getValues().flat().filter(String);
  var header = favs.shift();
  return [ss, item, favs_sheet, favs_range, favs, header]
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your time and effort! Tick/untick works on checkboxes but they do nothing. I tried to run the functions one by one through app scripts panel and i got this error when running onEdit: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 2, file "test")` this error when running add_item, remove_item and get_variables: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 29, file "test")`

Comment: Here is my spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lZ9KTkdcajtnww5Ap9BVSmaOJlRE1bYddF1a4DIs_Wk/edit?usp=sharing try it. It works fine for me.

Comment: If you share your spreadsheet (with some dummy data) I can try to figure out where is the problem.

Comment: And by the way, you can't run the `onEdit(e)` function from Script Editor. It fires automatically when you edit (click on checkboxes, etc) a sheet. But the triggers are hard things to debug, indeed. You have to go in Executions section to see what the error is happen or put functions in `try/catch(e)` container and show an alert window in the `catch()` branch.

Comment: Hello again! Here is the dummy data sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-lon8OcElcHmhLhaB5QZxvhbrrTVEwAa3cByio9njnQ
For any questions please let me know! Thank you again!

Comment: I just tweaked the code a bit to fit your spreadsheet. Here is the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1krgPZHsYToYCMtogQiBwTAfTf4kkwp3a7GaHDlaLZlI/edit?usp=sharing And probably you have to run `onEdit(e)` function from Script Editor first to set permissions. It will show the error first, but then is should work fine when you click on checkboxes on the sheet.

Comment: I found a bug, when you remove all cards from list and you add a new card it appears like this: https://puu.sh/ISIxs/830d0bd58c.png

Comment: Yes, indeed. There is something. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Cool! Thanks! Let me know once you fix it!

Comment: I've fixed (I hope). There was a problem with the header 'Cards' in the 'Favorites' sheet. Now it should work.

Comment: It works! Everything looks okay now! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey again, I was wondering what i have to change in script in order to paste/remove values only? Because right now when i remove a card it removes the format of whole column too.

Comment: Try `favs_range.clearContents();` instead `favs_range.clear();`

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work, it doesn't even clear data. Thanks

Comment: My bad. It turned out that a range has the method `clearContent()` without '**s**' at the end. Try it. A sheet has the method `clearContents()` with '**s**'. Go figure.

Comment: Well what can i say...you're the GOAT of google sheets! Thank you again!

Comment: Hey again, I was wondering what would I have to change in order to make your script run as assigned to an image instead of onEdit (checkbox)? So when user clicks on an image it runs the add_item function and when he clicks on another image it runs the remove_item function? Thanks

Comment: Hi! I think it won't be difficult, but the logic will be quite different, without the `e` object, etc. So I'd propose you to make a new question. It's not exactly convenient way to have two different algorithms (for different tasks actually) within one answer.

Comment: I just did! https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/127399201
It would be nice if you could take a look at it when you have the time! Thanks